# PHP UPDATE query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to a fix a problem with my code, that regard an user profile system. During registration user set their personal information, including address. Address value is used by API google maps.UPDATE query doesnt work.Why?
N.B: data type lat, lng are 'decimal(10,8)decimal(11,8)'

```
<?php
include("database.php");
session_start();


    $error = "";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
      $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
      $surname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
      $affiliation = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['affiliation']);
      $department = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['department']);
      $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
      $position = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['position']);
      $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
      $web = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['web']);
      $telephone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telephone']);
      $mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile']);
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      $passwordConfirm = $_POST['passwordConfirm'];
      $privacy = $_POST['privacy'];

      //validare i valori inseriti dall'utente
      if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
      {
        $error = "Inserisci una email valida ";
      }

      else if (strlen($password < 8)) {
        $error = "La password deve contenere almeni 8 caratteri";
      }

      else if ($password != $passwordConfirm)
      {
        $error = "Le password devono coincidere!";
      }

      else {
        $error = "Ti sei appena registrato su B";
      }


      $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, name, surname, affiliation, department,address,position,email,web,telephone,mobile,password,privacy) VALUES('$username','$name','$surname','$affiliation','$department','$address','$position','$email','$web','$telephone','$mobile','$password','$privacy')";
      mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));

      if($address !=''){
        $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$address."&sensor=true";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
        $status = $xml->status;
        if ($status=="OK"){
          $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
          $lng = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;

        }
        $sql1 = "UPDATE users SET lng='$lng', lat='$lat' WHERE username='$username'";
        mysqli_query($database,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error($database));
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what's the error message? [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: also, [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! – [Jay Blanchard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1011527/jay-blanchard)

Comment: Different updates parts must be separated with `,` and not with `AND`

Comment: `mysql_` != `mysqli_` make sure you use the write driver consistently.

Comment: Using PHP 7 would solve any mixed API issues in this code instantly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

instead of using `AND`, you need to separate with a comma `,`

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE users SET lng='$lng', lat='$lat' WHERE username='$username'";
```

Comment: try to add back-ticks , and everything is ok! :D +1 from me ;)

Comment: @FrancescoRaffAnselmi , what do you mean by "one time work and the other time no" .. can you please explain ?

Comment: Sorry. Only it works once. It seems that the UPDATE query functions just once and then crashes if you try a second filling in the form

Answer (score 2):

Do not use And and don't forget to add backticks :) and good to see that newbies are completely avoiding mysql_* :D

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE `users` SET `lng`='$lng', `lat`='$lat' WHERE `username`='$username'";
```

Comment: Except for using `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 1):

Replace AND with comma in update statement